# Finding series and sequence math

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value for the following series.
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\cos(n\pi) + \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right))
$$

Comment: Try working out the first few terms of the series and see if you notice any pattern.

Comment: Why do you think this converges?

Answer (score 4):

We can get an answer to this, a rather strange one, (and by the suggestion of @pspi, a Cesaro sum) by doing the following
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos n\pi+\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$$$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos n\pi+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$$
By [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series), we know that
$$1-1+1-1+1...=\frac{1}{2}$$
Which can also be written as;
$$\cos 0n +\cos 1n +\cos 2n + ... = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos1n + \cos 2n + ... = -\frac{1}{2}$$
Substituting that in the original summation, we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$$
Now here we can modify this a little better, because of the fact that $\sin \frac{2n\pi}{2}=0$
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Using the identity for $\sin A-B$, we get;
$$-\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos n\pi$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$=0$$

And hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos n\pi+\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}=0$$

Comment: $1-1+1-1+1...=\frac{1}{2}$ is a false statement. You could say that $1-1+1-1+1...$ has Cesàro $\frac{1}{2}$ but you can't mislead the sum itself to $\frac{1}{2}$. The series is divergent.

Comment: @Pspl, actually where did I claim that this is the right solution to the problem? Any kid can see that this doesn't have a clear solution and clearly diverges, all I was doing in your words, the Cesaro sum of the problem. I've added that bit to the answer for those who can't sense it.

Comment: You're totally right! And it's a interesting approach! But you may mislead the OP by saying $1-1+1-1+1...=\frac{1}{2}$ or even $\sum\cos n\pi+\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}=0$. If you edit your answer to clear this, I will remove my downvote! I will even give you an upvote! :)

Comment: All I'm saying is that the $\frac{1}{2}$ treatment can lead to some interesting findings, I've even seen someone using that to prove the Basel problem, (takes the usage of the Fourier series hidden in it)

Comment: please don't get me wrong! I'm just trying to get you to clarify your answer in a better way! After all, that was not what was asked! I know Cesàro sums and it's applications, so I agree with your answer! But not with your terminology. When you're saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)=0$ you are wrong! You shoud say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)=0$ While I get your spirits, but where is the $n$ in the expression? Is it the upper bound of the summation? And what does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)=0$ has to do here?

Comment: $S_n=\sum_{p=1}^{n}\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)$ is the partial sums sequence and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)$ converges if $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=S$. ${S_C}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=1}^{n}\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)$ is the partial Cesàro sums and the series is Cesàro convergent if $\lim_{n\to\infty}{S_C}_n=S_C$. You're saying that $S_C=0$, but writing $S=0$.

Comment: ${S_C}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=1}^{n}\left(\cos p\pi+\sin \frac{p\pi}{2}\right)$ is the partial Cesàro sums. Can you explain why this is the case? And what if I put the lower index, $p=0$?

Comment: It's not this case!! It's the definition! What if $p=0$??

Comment: For $p=0$, we get the Cesaro sum to be $1$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the partial sums sequence ($S_n$), you will find the series is divergent (ie. it doesn't have a sum):

$$S_n=\sum_{p = 1}^n \left[\cos(p\pi) + \sin\left(\frac{p\pi}2\right)\right]$$

If you calculate the first values of this sequence, you will notice immediately that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{S_n}$ doesn't exist:

$$S_1=0 \qquad S_2=1 \qquad S_3=-1 \qquad S_4=0 \qquad S_5=0 \qquad ...$$